# Are Skylanders "Adventure Packs" compatible with Skylanders Giants?

Tags: skylanders, skylanders-giants

I have some level packs from the first *Skylanders: Spyro's Adventures* I was wondering I they were usable in *Skylanders Giants* and if so in what way. Do they unlock different levels in the new game or just the old ones? Do they still work as a powerup item if placed mid level?

Comment: I thought that they didn't work so I looked it up and it was true. I ordered an adventure pack and sure enough, it worked. Now I can play with both series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They function more or less the same as in the first Skylanders game.  The level you unlock is the same, and has the same storyline, but the gameplay might be a little different since they took the same level layout but used enemies from Sky: Giants instead of just using the enemies from Sky1.  You can use it as a powerup item mid-level, although it might ask you if you want to play the Adventure level.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, literally everything from Skylanders Spyro's adventure can be used in Giants, and the re-makes but re-make lightcores from giants can't be used in spyro's adventure.